# mips64el-linux-android-g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-mfpu=neon'

Tags: c++, opencv, android-ndk

I am trying to run a NDK and OpenCV related project. The project builds errorless. But when i run the application I get the error:

> mips64el-linux-android-g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-mfpu=neon'

My Application.mk file looks like this:

```
APP_STL := gnustl_shared
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions

# NEON
APP_CFLAGS += -mfpu=neon
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
APP_PLATFORM := android-18
APP_OPTIM := debug
APP_MODULES := nVisoDemo-1.1
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.9
HAVE_LIB_CEVA := false # CUSTOM VARIABLE USED (NOT ANYMORE) IN Android.mk
```

Android.mk:

```
# Freeimage
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libfreeimage
LOCAL_ARM_NEON := true
#LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(NVISO_LIBS_DIR)/libfreeimage-3.14.so
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := D:/Siddharth/StudioProjects/OpenCVDemo/nvsdk/src/main/jni/Fr‌​amework/nviso/libs/a‌​rmeabi-v7a/libfreeim‌​age-3.14.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

I tried to remove APP_CFLAGS += -mfpu=neon from application.mk file but then it gives all the compilation errors in cpp files..

Also to mention that the above code works flawlessly in Eclipse...but the problem is coming in Android Studio only

Any help would be appreciated..Thanks in advance..

Comment: try removing '-mfpu=neon' , I guess this might solve the problem or just comment it out.

Comment: I tried by removing it, but then it gives me all the cpp related compilation errors....

Comment: Paste those CPP related error logs, it will help to follow what is happening? btw, just give `APP_CPPFLAGS:= `. delete -mfpu=neon

Comment: If i remove it gives these errors : 
Error:(145, 28) error: 'Implementation' is not a class or namespace
Error:(146, 18) error: 'InputImageFormat' is not a class or namespace
Error:(181, 28) error: 'Implementation' is not a class or namespace
Error:(145, 28) error: 'Implementation' is not a class or namespace
Error:(146, 18) error: 'InputImageFormat' is not a class or namespace
Error:(181, 28) error: 'Implementation' is not a class or namespace
Error:(104, 35) error: expected ',' or '...' before '&&' token

Comment: @LethalProgrammer solution worked...the error mentioned in question was no more there then i had errors in cpp files which were solved by my solution mentioned below in my comment answer..

Comment: Good, that's what I was suspected in the beginning you would have some cpp related errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello I solved the issue by the following way:

Actually what @LethalProgrammer said was rite. When I removed the "APP_CFLAGS += -mfpu=neon" line from Application.mk then it should have started working but when i removed the line it give all kind of errors in my cpp files.

So problem was that i was building using commandline and also i had put .so files in jnilibs folder in app so it was building twice..

> Thus i removed this from app's build.gradle
>   externalNativeBuild {
>           ndkBuild {
>               path 'D:/Siddharth/StudioProjects/OpenCVDemo/nvsdk/src/main/jni/Android.mk'
>           }
>       }

So at last removing the above code from build.gradle and removing -mfpu=neon from application.mk file it started working and the app run..
Thank you all...

Answer (score 1):

By default you'll build for every NDK ABI: arm5, arm7, arm64, mips, mips64, x86, and x86_64, but `-mfpu=neon` is only valid for arm7 and arm64.

In general for cases like this you need to protect architecture specific flags by testing against `TARGET_ARCH_ABI`, but for NEON support there's a flag just for this:

```
LOCAL_ARM_NEON := true
```

Add that to each of your modules in your Android.mk.

Comment: Hi I have 3 module definitions in the Android.mk one of them i sharing here where i have added as u said but the error is still there..:
# Freeimage
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libfreeimage
LOCAL_ARM_NEON := true
#LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(NVISO_LIBS_DIR)/libfreeimage-3.14.so
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := D:/Siddharth/StudioProjects/OpenCVDemo/nvsdk/src/main/jni/Framework/nviso/libs/armeabi-v7a/libfreeimage-3.14.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

Comment: Copied into the question (please don't put things like that in comments, it's unreadable). That module is a prebuilt. cflags/cppflags don't affect it at all.